# What happens to persistent effects generated by a magical item when it is not being worn/carried?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, curse-of-strahd

If you have a magic item that is capable of generating some sort of persistent, non-concentration effect, what happens when you remove/drop/give the item to someone who is not attuned to it?

Specifically I'm thinking about the **Holy Symbol of Ravenkind** from Curse of Strahd and its **Sunlight** property, but there might be other items that fall into this category.

> **HOLY SYMBOL OF RAVENKIND**
>
>  Wondrous item, legendary (requires attunement by a cleric or paladin of good alignment)
>
>  **Sunlight.** As an action, you can expend 5 charges while presenting the
>  holy symbol to make it shed bright light in a 30-foot radius and dim
>  light for an additional 30 feet. The light is sunlight and lasts for
>  10 minutes or until you end the effect (no action required).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have it in your possession when you “present” it. After that, you can put it down or give it to someone else and the light will continue “for 10 minutes or until you end the effect”.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you must have the item in your posession to be able to use it.
So I would rule that the light would stay, but it cannot be turned off or on until given to you.

Comment: Who is "you" in this answer. You may want to clarify that it is the character attuned to the item.

Comment: Do you have a citation or any proof of this assertion?

Comment: Yes, i have proof of part, even though not specifically stated in the PHB magic items must be in a characters posession to be used. My ruling is that "used" means interacted with.